# Custom ItemBuilder Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layoutbuilder

I want to create a custom itemBuilder for a widget that I am creating as it needs to have dynamic widgets for each use case.

How can I implement something like `ListView.builder(itemBuilder: ...)`'s item builder for my widget?

I tried creating a function as a parameter to get it to work but I was stuck after getting the function, I didn't know how to iterate through it.

```dart
class ViewClass extends StatelessWidget{
    ViewClass({
        this.key, 
        required this.itemBuilder,
    });

    final Function(Widget item) itemBuilder;
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(...);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter is open source, you could just try to look into `ListView.builder`'s source code (by control clicking it from your IDE) to look how it's done, but there's an even much simpler widget: `Builder`. It's probably the simplest widget that has such a feature. So simply look how they do it. And that's:

```
class Builder extends StatelessWidget {
  /// Creates a widget that delegates its build to a callback.
  const Builder({
    super.key,
    required this.builder,
  });

  /// Called to obtain the child widget.
  ///
  /// This function is called whenever this widget is included in its parent's
  /// build and the old widget (if any) that it synchronizes with has a distinct
  /// object identity. Typically the parent's build method will construct
  /// a new tree of widgets and so a new Builder child will not be [identical]
  /// to the corresponding old one.
  final WidgetBuilder builder;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => builder(context);
}
```

And here `WidgetBuilder` is defined as:

```
typedef WidgetBuilder = Widget Function(BuildContext context);
```

So what you did wrong is actually you defined `itemBuilder` as a Function that takes a widget as argument, but you needed one that returns it. So you could do this for example:

```
class ViewClass extends StatelessWidget{
  const ViewClass({
    super.key,
    required this.itemBuilder,
  });

  final Widget Function() itemBuilder;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: itemBuilder());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from what i understand,you trying to create a custom widget from a list view item if so you could do it like below. Note i am using a list of string as items as an example but you can use any Objects. kindly correct me if this is not what you are trying to do:

```
class ViewClass extends StatelessWidget {
  const ViewClass({
    super.key,
    required this.item,
  });

  final String item;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(item),
    );
  }
}

class MyListClass extends StatelessWidget {
  MyListClass({super.key});
  List<String> itemList = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: itemList.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var item = itemList[index];
        return ViewClass(item: item);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No i am trying to eliminate the use of listview builder i want to create a similar functionality to listview builder.